# Prove usual $\leq$ on R in [0,1] is a lattice.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

Let $R$ be the set of real numbers in $[0,1]$ and $\leq$ be the usual operation of "less than or equal to" on $R$. Show that $(R,\leq)$ is a lattice.

Definition of Lattice: A poset in which every pair of elements has a GLB and LUB.

Comment: You should write out the definition of lattice and what you have tried.  (This should be very straightforward after you write out the definition).

Comment: I know the definition. Also i can prove it in my mind that the relation is reflexive, antisymmetric and transive. Moreover I can also understand that each pair of this set has a GLB and LUB. But I am not able to prove this showing steps.

Comment: Ok, so then what is the greatest lower bound of the set $\{ 0.3, 0.5 \}$?

Comment: GLB of set {0.3,0.5} is 0.3. I can prove taking examples. But I want to prove using any element x,y,z belonging to lattice.

Comment: Ok, yes that's right.  So if I have a two element set $\{x, y\}$ where each $x, y \in [0, 1]$ the greatest lower bound is a lower bound, so it is $\leq$ both $x$ and $y$.  But also, it is the greatest such so we don't want to go too small.  So what if we pick one of $x$ or $y$?  Will that always work?  And if so, which one should I pick?

Comment: It works under this relation i.e. "less than or equal to" but may not work under other relation such as "divides". We may pick x here..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10793/discussion-between-user221458-and-ryan-sullivant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ll use $\land$ for the lattice operation of *meet*, *infimum*, or *greatest lower bound* and $\lor$ for the operation of *join*, *supremum*, or *least upper bound*. (All of these terms are used.)

Suppose that $x,y\in\Bbb R$; when is a real number $a$ a lower bound for the set $\{x,y\}$? Clearly it’s when $a\le x$ and $a\le y$, so $a$ is a lower bound for $\{x,y\}$ if and only if $a\le\min\{x,y\}$. Let $L(x,y)=L(y,x)$ be the set of all lower bounds of $\{x,y\}$; then we’ve just seen that

$$L=\{a\in\Bbb R:a\le\min\{x,y\}\}\;.$$

Does $L$ have a largest element? Yes: $\max L=\min\{x,y\}$. In other words, $\min\{x,y\}$ is the greatest lower bound, or meet, of $x$ and $y$, and we define $$x\land y=\min\{x,y\}\;.$$

With this as a model can you do the other half of the argument? It’s very similar.

Comment: x ∨ y = max{x,y}

Comment: @user221458: Yes, it is indeed the maximum of $x$ and $y$. And the argument is essentially the same, but with $\le$ and $\ge$ reversed.

Comment: So is it proved?

Comment: @user221458: If you can write out the same sort of argument that I used, only this time to show that $\max\{x,y\}$ really is the least upper bound of $x$ and $y$, because it’s less than or equal to every upper bound.

Comment: yeah. I got it. but don't we have to show that it is also a poset? Does only showing that each pair of elements has a LUB and GLB proves it a lattice?

Comment: @user221458: You do have to show that it’s a poset, but that’s straightforward: $\langle\Bbb R,\le\rangle$ is a standard example of a linear order (you may use the term *total order* instead), and every linear order is a partial order — reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive — with the extra property that for any $x$ and $y$, either $x\le y$ or $y\le x$. It wouldn’t hurt to say explicitly that $\langle\Bbb R,\le\rangle$ satisfies each of the three properties required of a partial order, just to prove to the grader that you know what they are!