# Prove that Idempotent property of lattices follows from commutative, associative and absorption property.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

I tried but I am not able to prove this. I am able to prove $a+a=a$ but not $a\cdot a=a$.

This is what i did so far:

$$a+(a\cdot b)=a+a=a.$$

Thus $a+a=a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve already shown that $a+a=a$. and you know that $a\cdot(a+b)=a$ for all $b$; substitute $b=a$ into that absorption law and simplify using your previous result.

Comment: Thanks. Please help me on this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507472/prove-usual-leq-on-r-in-0-1-is-a-lattice

Comment: @user221458: You’re welcome; I’ll take a look.